# Is there a good example (and name) of a floating button which appears between rows/columns?

Tags: controls, custom-control

I'm imagining a way of inserting a new row or column, where when the cursor approaches the outer vertex of a row or column (where the divider meets the outer edge), a button with a `+` appears allowing a new one to be inserted there.

Here's a mockup I made to demonstrate my idea:
[image]

**Are there any real-world examples of apps that do this?** Additionally, what is this called?

Comment: Isn't it a Tooltip?

Comment: @Alvaro no, because it can be clicked and provides no "tip"

Answer (score 1):

A number of website builders use this pattern to allow users to insert content between blocks. Take SquareSpace: [image]

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is just a button or according to Google Material a [Floating action button](https://material.google.com/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button).

[image]

Image source: https://material.google.com/layout/principles.html#principles-floating-action-button